# removing specific warnings in Apache error.log

Tags: apache-2.2

Here's my situation. I have a directive that goes something like this:

`Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks`

I have a location directive where I have

`Options +Includes`

This causes warning errors in my Apache error log:

`mod_include: Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec) wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed`

These warnings are gone when I add `+Includes` to my options but I don't want. I want to have the Includes filter removed but without having warning errors.

If there's something unclear, feel free to ask. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Options cannot be within a Location block. See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#whatwhere

Comment: And http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to not see the warning in the logs, you can add a filter to remove them in your syslog configuration.

Comment: Apache does not log to syslog unless it has been configured to.

Comment: That's right, but you can configure it for that.

Answer (score 0):

LogLevel error or LogLevel crit would eliminate those messages.